# Conditional statement in sum() function of R

Tags: r, sum

I've started learning R and got a piece of code in which a statement is:

```
if(sum(C == C[i]) == 1)# C is simply a vector and i is index of a value in this vector which the user specifies in an argument.
```

How can you pass a conditional statement as an argument of a function? Also explain the meaning of this statement.

Thank you.

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. You did not specified `C` and the `if`-construct is not complete.

Comment: @jogo why would I add extra code which may be completely irrelevant from the question, also I did mention the meaning of C in the comment following the if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take an example to understand

Consider `C` as a numeric vector from 1 to 10 and let's take `i` as 3

```
C <- 1:10
i <- 3
```

So when we do

```
C == C[i]
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

it compares every element of `C` with `C[i]` which is 3 and returns a corresponding logical vector which is only `TRUE` at 3rd index.

When we `sum` this logical vector it returns count of all `TRUE` (as it considers `FALSE` as 0 and `TRUE` as 1) values which in this case is 1

```
sum(C == C[i])
#[1] 1
```

which is then compared to 1 again to make sure that there is only one `C[i]` in `C`

```
sum(C == C[i]) == 1
#[1] TRUE
```

This will fail in case if we have repeated numbers in `C`. For example,

```
C <- c(1:10, 3) #Adding an extra 3 in the end
C
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  3
i <- 3
sum(C == C[i]) == 1
#[1] FALSE
```

---

The bottom line is the condition is `TRUE` if `C[i]` occurs only once in `C`.